# Not able to apply security patch SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-6285

We have a Magento website having version 1.9.1.0 (CE). As I got the update from Magento support, to apply security patch on your store to prevent from security threat. We have downloaded the secutiry patch

> PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh

We have uploaded this patch on my root folder of test environment and then applied. But we got the error for my following files and patch is not applying:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file downloader/lib/.htaccess
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
checking file errors/processor.php
Done
```

I don't know what's the meaning of above messages so that I can fix the issues. I also tried the same thing on default Magento system having same version, but got the same error.

Can anyone share us that why I am getting error and how can I fix the same?

Answer (score 10):

this is because you have not applied previous patches 5994

[image]

```
diff --git downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
index 1e5a7e0..90562f5 100644
--- downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
+++ downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@
 Extension dependencies
 <form action="<?php
     echo $this->url('connectInstallPackagePost')?>" method="post" target="connect_iframe" onsubmit="onSubmit(this)">
-    <input type="hidden" name="install_package_id" value="<?php echo $this->get('package_id'); ?>">
+    <input type="hidden" name="install_package_id" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->get('package_id')); ?>">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
         <col width="150" />
         <col width="250" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if patches can't be applied, check:

Are you using the right patch version for your Magento version?
Do the files that the patch fails to update present or have they been changed? Replace them with original files from your Magento version and apply the patch again.